# Is there a way to set a Public (Elastic) IP for a machine in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

Is there a way to set a Public (Elastic) IP for a machine in AWS? I'm using Packer from w/in a corp network. We have to explicitly whitelist IPs as SSH targets. Is there a way to, when Packer starts an EC2 instance for image build, have it get a specific Elastic IP address?

Comment: You CANT assign specific external IP addresses. Amazon assigns them randomly.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you already have the elastic IPs allocated and you want to assign one of the IPs from that pool. There is no way to assign the IP when starting. Instead upload a script using **FileProvisioner**. The script will execute a AWS CLI command to assign the IP of your choice to your instance.

```
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id <your-instance-id> --public-ip <your-elastic-IP>
```

Then use **ShellProvisioner** to execute that script.

Comment: Hm. But I need Packer to be able to initially SSH into the machine targeting a specific VIP. So, it sounds like what I need doesn't exist but you did offer a great solution for other needs. Thank you.